# como conectar mi base datos Oracle a Power BI?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, powerbi

Tengo una base de Datos de Tipo Oracle, que trabajo con sql developer, necesito poder hacer visualizaciones en el programa Power BI como poder hacer esta conexión?, he investigado un poco y tengo entendido que debo instalar primeramente el client de oracle... pero no he dado con como hacerlo.

Agradezco la ayuda!

Comment: Si en Power BI vas a "Obtener datos" tienes una opción para Oracle (en "Todo" o en "Bases de datos")

Answer (score 0):

Para conectarte a una base de datos Oracle con Power BI Desktop debes instalar el cliente de oracle el cual te va a proveer de los drivers de conexion.

Los pasos a modo general serian los siguientes:

- Identificar la version de Power BI que tienes instalada, basicamente
  necesitas saber si es 32 bits o 64 bits.
- Descargar el cliente de oracle dependiendo de la version de tu Power
  BI (32 bist o 64 bits).
  [Link32](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html)
  [Link64](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)
- Intalar el cliente de Oracle
- Conectarte a la base de datos desde Power BI

Te dejo este [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-oracle-database) con informacion oficial de Microsoft donde te podras guiar para cumplir los pasos que te mencione anteriormente.